# sprintf() Versus mysql_query()

Tags: php, sql, mysql, printf, mysql-error-1065

Having trouble formatting my code to execute without error using sprintf() When I run the code I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /location on line 16

```
 $query = sprintf('UPDATE `%s` SET `stock` = :amount WHERE `itemname` = '$q'', $tablename);
```

Above is line 16 in my code. I'm assuming it is syntax related.

I am now receiving the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in /home/content/63/6563663/html/inventory/pg.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/63/6563663/html/inventory/pg.php(19): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/content/63/6563663/html/inventory/pg.php on line 19

This is my entire code block:

```
 <?php

 $u=$_GET["u"];

 if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form2")) {
 $amount = isset($_POST['amount']) ? $_POST['amount'] : null;
 if (null != $amount) {

 $user = 'username';
 $pass = 'password';
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost', $user, $pass);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 session_start();
 $tablename = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
 $query = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET stock= :amount WHERE itemname= '.$u, $tablename);
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($UpdateQuery);
 $stmt->bindParam('amount', $amount);
 $stmt->execute();
 }
 }

 ?>
```

Thank you, seems my error is dealing with the PDO execution, not the query itself. If anyone has any ideas on that it would be great. Alan, I used your method for the quotes and also am running the query through mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: You have a syntax error: You need to escape your single quote. `\'` Where does `$q` come from? It is properly `mysql_real_escape_string()` ed?

Comment: $q is just a simple string defined earlier in my code block.

Comment: I'm curious to see if the table name is being enclosed by single quotes *within* the backticks.  Can you update the question to include the query printout prior to execution?

Comment: _sigh_, `$query  !== $UpdateQuery`., enable notices while developing to catch those pesky non-existing variables.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not build SQL queries out of variables.  Use bind variables.

See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$query = sprintf('UPDATE`%s`SET`stock`= :amount WHERE`itemname`= '.$q, $tablename);`

You need to put a concatenation operator between strings and variables to combine them together.  You also can get rid of the `''` after `$q` because it is not changing the string at all.

Edit:

I believe I misread what you are trying to do.  Try this instead:

`$query = sprintf("UPDATE`%s`SET`stock`= :amount WHERE`itemname`= '$q'", $tablename);`

By changing your PHP string to be within double quotes, you do not need to escape your single quotes, and $q will be expanded to its value.

Also, be sure that you run $q and $tablename through `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `%s` SET `stock` = :amount WHERE `itemname` = \'$q\'', $tablename);
```

or

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `%s` SET `stock` = :amount WHERE `itemname` = \'$q\'", $tablename);
```

You can't have unescaped `'`s in strings delimited by `'`. Either unescaped `"`s in strings delimited by `"`. To escape the string delimiter you need to prepend a `\` character.